# C compiler cannot create executables when installing gcc AND binutils

Tags: linux-mint, gcc, executable, configure

I've been having a problem with building pretty much any GNU program. I try to build Binutils, or GCC using:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However, `./configure` always seems to throw the error:

```
configure: error: in `/home/user/Desktop/binutils-2.28':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

This happens on both Binutils and GCC. I tried everything from other questions and articles, but nothing solves it...

I'm mostly asking for help with GCC, because I need that one the most. (Binutils is pre-installed on my system.)

++++ Config.log Output for GCC ++++

https://pastebin.com/BJzNMjG2

Comment: Does it work if you configure it without the explicit `--build`, `--host`, `--target` parameters (i.e. keep everything native)? Can you successfully build a simple "hello world" C program?

Comment: @steeldriver It doesn't build even without those parameters... I'm also trying to target i686-elf as I'm developing a kernel.

Comment: What/who is `/home/user`? By the PATH I guess you run the script as `james`? Is this correct? Does james have permissions in `/home/user/...`?

Comment: @thomas `/home/user/` is the same as `james`. That is my user. (Which is an administrator.)

Comment: The option `--enable-langauges=c` seems like a typo. Did ./configure supply that option on its own?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, according to osdev, it tells gcc to exclude all languages but that one... Is this not supposed to be there?

Comment: Yes, but it should be spelled `--enable-languages`. Either way, it's probably not the cause of configure's failure, but I was curious about it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Ah, didn't catch that.

Comment: Why are you trying to build binutils and gcc by hand? Your distribution must have these both. Presumably the C compiler that you say doesn't work is gcc. Was that also built by hand or is it a distribution binary package?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, it comes with both Binutils and GCC 5.4.0, however, I was told that I couldn't use my system compiler to do this, so I'm trying to install a new GCC copy.

Comment: "however, I was told that I couldn't use my system compiler to do this" Couldn't use it to do what?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm using GCC to develop an operating system. However I can't configure the pre-installed GCC to target i686-elf as it doesn't have configure.ac in its root directory.

Comment: Ah, finally some answers. Ok, it would probably be much easier to customize your existing Debian binary to do what you want. What you'd need to do is take the Debian gcc sources, and first rebuild them to make sure they build for you, which they should. Then figure out how you need to modify the build so that the resulting binary has the properties you want. (But what is "its root directory" here, and why is it necessary to have `configure.ac` in there?) If you can't figure out how to do this, that would be a reasonable question to ask here, imo.

Answer (score 5):

`gcc` as a standalone install will not be usable for compiling on the most 'Linux OS'. Install g++ (gcc-c++) and the missing parts will be installed too.

How to build gcc : gcc requires a build folder outside the gcc-7.1.0/ source !
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html

Unpack gmp, mpfr, mpc as described in the link, and you can configure, from build/ , example:

```
../gcc-7.1.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc7 --program-suffix=7 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
```